# Can't seem to figure out why am I not getting an alert after clicking a button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short, up until now I have only been using html, css and php for my website. I added the ability to be able to upvote and downvote images, however, since I don't want the page to refresh every time I upvote or downvote, I did a quick search and found out I'd have to use jquery. After including my jquery and javascript files in the footer, I decided to write a simple piece of code to see if I'll get an alert when I click the upvote button. Here's the code

```
$('.arrowUp').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Unfortunately, when I click the upvote button, the alert doesn't pop up for some reason so I can only assume that whatever code I write in that function, it's not gonna work until I figure out why is the alert not popping.

This is my upvote button code.

```
if ($hasVoted < 1) {
            echo    "<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'><form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form>";
                    </div>
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the close `<div>` tag be inside the string with the rest of the code?

Comment: Ops, that's my bad, originally that div is not supposed to be there but since I had to cut the code I added it manually but forgot to put it inside

Comment: This: `value='".$row[' id ']."'` seems to be confusing for the JavaScript. (Look at the quotes)

Comment: So what can I do about it?

Comment: You can make it ignore the single quotes the string like this: `value=\'".$row['id']."\'`

Comment: The problem may be in that the `<img>` is inside a submit form `<button>`, which is inside a form.

Comment: I tried selecting the header, body, html and several other elements in jquery and still nothing happens. I tried doing this on a blank document from scratch and it worked out OK. I can only assume finding the issue is gonna be painful. Jquery and Javascript are definitely included since I have been using them prior to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151795/discussion-between-james-douglas-and-peter-atanasov).

Comment: can you try this syntax: `$('.arrowUp').on('click',function(){
    alert('hello');
});`

Comment: Is the php code run in the file itself or is the echo received through ajax? Before the click event is set, the element needs to be in the dom already. Just checking. You can try inserting that same .click function directly into the console of your browser, and then see if it works. Or enter $('.arrowUp') and see if it actually returns a selected element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that jQuery is properly included, I think the problem lies in the `<img>` which is in a `type="submit"` `<button>`, which is inside a form. Naturally, when you click the submit button it tries to submit the form.

```js
$('.arrowUp').click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
  <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='currentUser'>
    <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example above, the alert doesn't happen. Now, with the exact same code except the `<img>` *outside* the button,

```js
$('.arrowUp').click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
  <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='currentUser'>
    <img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'>
    <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

It appears the OP had a script error which was causing the error, which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

add the `arrowUp` class to `<button>` instead of `<ima>`

```
 <div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'><form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                    <button class='upvoteImageButton arrowUp' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'>
                    <img src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
                </form>";
                </div>
```

Comment: What would be the difference between putting arrowUp in the button classes and just using upvoteImageButton as a selector in jquery? I tried both ways and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Put the arrowUp class in button.

```
<button class='upvoteImageButton arrowUp' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'>
      <img src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'>
</button>
```

Or
Place the image alongside button not inside of it.

And of course wrap you js code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.arrowUp').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

select `.upvoteImageButton` in Jquery selector instead of `.arrowUp`, and by the way are you sure you are loading jquery after the document is loaded.